# Expo Asset library works in debug but not in release (Expo ejected project/React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I try to get a `.jpg` file absolute path on `Android`. I'm using `Expo Asset` library for this. While my application runs in `debug mode`, everything is working as expected. The `Expo Asset` library returns my file with the correct `localUri` path but in `release mode` the `localUri` property contains only the name of the file and not the actual path.
As an example on `debug` the `localUri` contains the following: `file:///data/user/0/com.test.app/cache/ExponentAsset-10f8d3f8108915f49694bdd86e85fcbd.jpg`
while in `release` the same property will contain `assets_bg_img`

The following line is the request:

```
backgroundUri = await Asset.loadAsync(require('../../assets/bg_img.jpg'));
```

And this is the commands I use to build my `release` apk:

```
cd android
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

This is the commands I use to run the app in `debug`:

```
npx react-native start --port 8084 --reset-cache
npx react-native run-android --port 8084
```

Is there a way to make this work? Or is there a better solution to get a file absolute path on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using the `Expo File System` library:

```
const imgUri = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}/bg_img.jpg`;
await FileSystem.copyAsync({from: 'asset://assets/images/bg_img.jpg', to: imgUri });
```

I also created an asset image folder under: `/android/app/src/main/assets/images` and added my `.jpg` file there.

Answer (score 0):

Building in release mode just like that is not enough in my experience. You need to follow these steps when building for release:

1. `./gradlew clean`
2. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`
3. `./gradlew assembleRelease`

As you can see, bundling is required first in order to successfully package everything for release.

Comment: I used the above commands and I have the same result.